# warning when assert() modifies variables

Tags: c++

Is there anything I can do to get a compiler warning when one modifies a variable inside an `assert()` or a `debug_print()`?

I want to prevent mistakes like these from happening

```
int i=0;
assert((++i)); // i is modified only in debug mode

std::set<int> s;
debug_print(("item inserted: %d\n", s.insert(5).first )); // set is modified only in debug mode
```

Suppose I have set of wrapper functions that are built on debug mode only, where I can do the necessary checks

```
MyDbgAssert() // #define that wraps assert()
MyDbgPrint()  // #define that wraps printf()
```

Comment: Whoever writes such asserts must suffer a severe talking to. (And if I were you, I'd elevate the warning level - if it exists - to an error).

Comment: Most cases of side effects in code that becomes compiled out are quite hard to detect. Even more so when you don't want false positives.

Comment: I'd recommend one of the more elaborate Static Analysis tools, such as Coverity, Parasoft or Klocwork.  These tools examine your source code for such mistakes.  There are also lower cost SA tools, but I'm not sure they will catch the issues you are talking about.

Answer (score 2):

There are tools (e.g., Coverity) that detect side-effects in macros/assertions.  CERT provides a [list of such tools](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/EXP31-C.+Avoid+side+effects+in+assertions)

Answer (score 0):

Unit tests will detect this kind of error if you run them religiously on both debug and release builds.